# Can an employment agency enforce a clause forbidding those who work for it disclosing for which companies they have worked?

Tags: united-states, employment

[This answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/147145/i-was-offered-software-developer-position-in-a-multi-billion-dollar-company-base/147150#147150) on S.E's "the Workplace" says

> The employment agreement might prohibit disclosing the names of specific clients.

To what extent is that legally enforceable?

I can understand that I may not be allowed to say on my CV/resume that I worked for certain government departments, but how is it in general? Further, I can see how a government department can, and can require the agency to pass that requirement on, but I do not believe that such a clause by an agency would hold up, as it is liable to deprive the signer of the the means of earning a living.

Can Agency, Inc really take legal action if my CV and my statements at interview say that I worked ***at*** (not for) BigCompany, Inc, on a contract basis?

As per my answer to [Working for a big company “through” another small company. Can I say I'm working for the first?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/146133/working-for-a-big-company-through-another-small-company-can-i-say-im-working/146145#146145)

> If you want to keep you conscience clear(ish), you could always say "I work at BigCompany, Inc" and let others draw their own conclusions.
>
> I will enlarge a little.
>
> I have been a software contractor for much longer than you have been alive, and use "I work for" since BigCompany gains from my work (more than the middle-man); they use the software that I develop, while the agent only takes a cut.
>
> But, the important part here is where you ask

`Now, the question is, am I wrong in writing on my resume that I'm a consultant for BigCompany?`

> You could do that.
>
> 2017 - 2109 BigCompany, Inc, Position: consultant
>
> Personally, I put
>
> 2017 - 2109 BigCompany, Inc, Position: senior software engineer
>
> But I would never, ever, ever name an agency on my CV.
>
> The reason is that hiring managers in the industry can gauge your suitability from companies where you have worked. So, having experience at British Aerospace is of interest to a hiring manager at Boeing, etc

It may also be worth mentioning that I am security cleared in Europe and work on sensitive government/military projects, and find risible the idea that a potential employer not be allowed to know of my employment history.

Tl;dr - can an employment agency enforce a clause forbidding those who work for it disclosing for which companies they have worked?

I have added a[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) tag, as that is where the original question is based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They likely can.

This information would likely fall under an NDA (Non-Disclosure Agreement) clause in the contract with the contracting company. The other clients of the contracting company could be considered confidential information, e.g., a client list, which can be covered by an NDA.

An NDA will usually have a term for duration and a term for breach consequences.

However, it is unlikely that an NDA would apply to prevent disclosure of other companies if the contracting company posts [all? | some?] of their clients publicly, such as in advertisements or blog posts online.

For some more information, you may check out this post from [LegalTemplates](https://legaltemplates.net/resources/business/information-you-can-and-cannot-protect-with-a-non-disclosure-agreement/).